# TensorFlow Dataset adding tiled images to batch dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

If I have a dataset of images which I have created into tiles what is the best way to combine the tile dimension with the batch dimension?

For example my input files are of shape (300,300,3) a typical RGB image with 300x300 pixels.

I do preprocessing and create a tile dataset which creates a new shape: (?,100,128,128,3)
So I have create 100 tiles of size 30x30 from the original image, and reshaped each tile to 128x128 pixels and then cached the dataset and created a batch with dimension ?.

Now I want to combine the tiles into the batch dimension and get a shape of: (?,128,128,3)

I've tried mapping the dataset to this function:

```
def reshape_image(image_batch):

    return tf.reshape(image_batch, (-1,128,128,3))
```

But this doesn't seem to be working as it is causing the iterator to hang on this call:

```
image_test = next(iter(image_ds))
```

Comment: It would help if you can provide full codes you have tried. How do you get `image_ds`, what's the shape of `image_batch`?

Comment: Right I should probably add that. I figured there would be some simple tensorflow operation to take a general batched format (?,N,X,Y,C) and convert it to (?+N,X,Y,C).

Comment: Do you want to get rid of some elements? These two tensor have different number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, the answer was fairly simple if you are familiar with the Tensorflow operations, hopefully this question wasn't too confusing and it helps someone out there.

```
#load/preprocess images from paths
image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
#split images into tiles so (X,Y,C) -> (N,X,Y,C) where N is the number of tiles
image_ds = image_ds.map(split_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
#resize tiled images from 30x30 to 128x128, implementation doesn't really matter
image_ds = image_ds.map(resize_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

#finally the answer!! use 'flat_map', 'unstack', and 'from_tensor_slices'
#tiled_images is of shape (N,X,Y,C)

def flat_map_impl(tiled_images):

  #You return a new Dataset
  #Unstack by default creates a list of tensors based on the first dimension
  #therefore tf.unstack(tiled_images) is a list of size N with (X,Y,C) shaped elements
  #finally from_tensor_slices creates a new dataset where each element is of shape (X,Y,C)
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.unstack(tiled_images))

#call flat_map_impl with flat_map on the dataset
image_ds = image_ds.flat_map(flat_map_impl)
```

Comment: a decent thread explaining image splitting into tiles is here for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235643/getting-started-with-tensorflow-split-image-into-sub-images the other mapped functions are explained in the Tensorflow documentation tutorials